# Internet Explorer and Border around Image IN iFrame

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet, image

so I am trying to fix some css issues with a site I am working on, and everything looks pretty much the same except for 1 iFrame element.

The iFrame contains a picture that is randomly generated, and a button that you click that will redirect you to another page. All functionality works, its just the styling. No matter what I try I cannot remove a 2px border around an img tag thats embedded inside an iFrame element. On the actual page that I am putting in an iFrame, there is no border around the image in all 3 browsers, so for some reason IE wants to put another border on this img tag when its in an iFrame on the main page...

This is the iFrame embedded in the main page.

```
<iframe src="~/Photos/PhotoViewer.aspx" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" class="PhotoViewer"></iframe>
```

and this is the css class

```
.PhotoViewer
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

This is part of the embedded page

```
.noBorder
{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server" class="noBorder" style="margin:0px;">
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Photos/Default.aspx" Target="_parent" class="noBorder"><img id="randPhoto" runat="server" alt="Photo Unavailable" class="noBorder"/></asp:HyperLink>
    <div style="border:none">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUploadPhoto" OnClick="btnUploadPhoto_Click" class="button" style="border:none"/>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

I have tried using most suggestions I could find on this site such as:

```
a, img {border:none;}
img {border:none;}
```

I used the css debugging feature for IE (F12) and I have found that even with me putting all these border: none/border: 0px around the img it still puts a 2px border around it. How can I force a css style onto an img element inside an iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your CSS in the embedded page to this;

```
.noBorder img
{
border:none;
outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck... The actual page not embedded in an iFrame, will show no border around the image at all. But for some reason when I embed the page within an iFrame IE will put a border around the image

Comment: Does the embedded page have the 
    border:none;
    outline:none; 
in the CSS?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what happened, but after inserting that code, it appears to work on the live site. It may have been a cache issue or something, but for now it is gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you don't apply a DOCTYPE to the main HTML then IE handles things however it wants to... which includes putting a border around stuff.

Or if you are using an older version of Internet Explorer, or forcing a newer Internet Explorer to render as an old Internet Explorer would through this meta tag: X-UA-Compatible